# Gaps And Islands: Splitting Islands Based On External Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

My scenario started off similar to a Island and Gaps problem, where I needed to find consecutive days of work. My current SQL query answers "ProductA was produced at LocationA from DateA through DateB, totaling X quantity".

However, this does not suffice when I needed to throw prices into the mix. Prices are in a separate table and handled in C# after the fact. Price changes are essentially a list of records that say "ProductA from LocationA is now Y value per unit effective DateC".

The end result is it works as long as the island does not overlap with a price-change date, but if it does overlap, I get a "close" answer, but it's not precise.

The C# code can handle applying the prices efficiently, what I need to do though is split the islands based on price changes. My goal is to make the SQL's partioning take into account the ranking of days from the other table, but I'm having trouble applying what I want to do.

---

The current SQL that generates my island is as follows

```
SELECT MIN(ScheduledDate) as StartDate, MAX(ScheduledDate) as 
EndDate, ProductId, DestinationId, SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity
FROM (
    SELECT ScheduledDate, DestinationId, ProductId, PartitionGroup = DATEADD(DAY ,-1 * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ScheduledDate), ScheduledDate), Quantity
    FROM History
) tmp
GROUP BY PartitionGroup, DestinationId, ProductId;
```

The current SQL that takes from the PriceChange table and ranks the dates is as follows

```
DECLARE @PriceChangeDates TABLE(Rank int, SplitDate Date);
INSERT INTO @PriceChangeDates
SELECT DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY EffectiveDate) as Rank, EffectiveDate as SplitDate
FROM ProductPriceChange
GROUP BY EffectiveDate;
```

---

My thought is to somehow update the first queries inner SELECT statement to somehow take advantage of the @PriceChangeDates table created by the second query. I would think we can multiply the DATEADD's increment parameter by the rank from the declared table, but I am struggling to write it.

If I was to somehow do this with loops, my thought process would be to determine which rank the ScheduledDate would be from the @PriceChangeDates table, where its rank is the rank of the closest Date that is smaller than itself it can find. Then take whatever rank that gives and, I would think, multiply it by the increment parameter being passed in (or some math, for example doing a *@PriceChangeDates.Count() on the existing parameter and then adding in the new rank to avoid collisions). However, that's "loop" logic not "set" logic, and in SQL I need to think in sets.

---

Any and all help/advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

---

UPDATE:

Sample data & example on SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/af568/1

Where the data is:

```
CREATE TABLE History
(
ProductId int,
DestinationId int,
ScheduledDate date,
Quantity float
);

INSERT INTO History (ProductId, DestinationId, ScheduledDate, Quantity)
VALUES
  (0, 1000, '20180401', 5),
  (0, 1000, '20180402', 10),
  (0, 1000, '20180403', 7),
  (3, 5000, '20180507', 15),
  (3, 5000, '20180508', 23),
  (3, 5000, '20180509', 52),
  (3, 5000, '20180510', 12),
  (3, 5000, '20180511', 14);

CREATE TABLE PriceChange
(
  ProductId int,
  DestinationId int,
  EffectiveDate date,
  Price float
);

INSERT INTO PriceChange (ProductId, DestinationId, EffectiveDate, Price)
VALUES
  (0, 1000, '20180201', 1),
  (0, 1000, '20180402', 2),
  (3, 5000, '20180101', 5),
  (3, 5000, '20180510', 20);
```

The desired results would be to have a SQL statement that generates the result:

```
StartDate   EndDate     ProductId   DestinationId   TotalQuantity
2018-04-01  2018-04-01  0           1000            5
2018-04-02  2018-04-03  0           1000            17
2018-05-07  2018-05-09  3           5000            90
2018-05-10  2018-05-11  3           5000            26
```

To clarify, the end result does need the TotalQuantity of each split amount, so the procedural code that manipulates the results and applies the pricing knows how much of each product was one on each side of the price change to accurately determine the values.

Comment: Right, my bad. Let me quickly make a SQL Fiddle of the problem...

Comment: Fiddles are nice, but include the sample data and desired results in the question itself as well so that it will be useful to future readers when the fiddle link goes dead.

Comment: Alright I added sample data/expected results to the body, and also made a fiddle link. Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straight-forward method is to fetch the effective price for each row of `History` and then generate gaps and islands taking price into account.

It is not clear from the question what is the role of `DestinationID`. Sample data is of no help here.
I'll assume that we need to join and partition on both `ProductID` and `DestinationID`.

The following query returns effective `Price` for each row from `History`.
You need to add index to the `PriceChange` table

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX] ON [dbo].[PriceChange]
(
    [ProductId] ASC,
    [DestinationId] ASC,
    [EffectiveDate] DESC
)
INCLUDE ([Price])
```

for this query to work efficiently.

**Query for Prices**

```
SELECT
    History.ProductId
    ,History.DestinationId
    ,History.ScheduledDate
    ,History.Quantity
    ,A.Price
FROM
    History
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            PriceChange.Price
        FROM
            PriceChange
        WHERE
            PriceChange.ProductID = History.ProductID
            AND PriceChange.DestinationId = History.DestinationId
            AND PriceChange.EffectiveDate <= History.ScheduledDate
        ORDER BY
            PriceChange.EffectiveDate DESC
    ) AS A
ORDER BY ProductID, ScheduledDate;
```

For each row from `History` there will be one seek in this index to pick the correct price.

This query returns:

**Prices**

```
+-----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------+
| ProductId | DestinationId | ScheduledDate | Quantity | Price |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------+
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-01    |        5 |     1 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-02    |       10 |     2 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-03    |        7 |     2 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-07    |       15 |     5 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-08    |       23 |     5 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-09    |       52 |     5 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-10    |       12 |    20 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-11    |       14 |    20 |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------+
```

---

Now a standard gaps-and-island step to collapse consecutive days with the same price together. I use a difference of two row number sequences here.

I've added some more rows to your sample data to see the gaps within the same `ProductId`.

```
INSERT INTO History (ProductId, DestinationId, ScheduledDate, Quantity)
VALUES
  (0, 1000, '20180601', 5),
  (0, 1000, '20180602', 10),
  (0, 1000, '20180603', 7),
  (3, 5000, '20180607', 15),
  (3, 5000, '20180608', 23),
  (3, 5000, '20180609', 52),
  (3, 5000, '20180610', 12),
  (3, 5000, '20180611', 14);
```

If you run this intermediate query you'll see how it works:

```
WITH
CTE_Prices
AS
(
    SELECT
        History.ProductId
        ,History.DestinationId
        ,History.ScheduledDate
        ,History.Quantity
        ,A.Price
    FROM
        History
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP(1)
                PriceChange.Price
            FROM
                PriceChange
            WHERE
                PriceChange.ProductID = History.ProductID
                AND PriceChange.DestinationId = History.DestinationId
                AND PriceChange.EffectiveDate <= History.ScheduledDate
            ORDER BY
                PriceChange.EffectiveDate DESC
        ) AS A
)
,CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        ProductId
        ,DestinationId
        ,ScheduledDate
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, DestinationId, Price ORDER BY ScheduledDate) AS rn1
        ,DATEDIFF(day, '20000101', ScheduledDate) AS rn2
    FROM
        CTE_Prices
)
SELECT *
    ,rn2-rn1 AS Diff
FROM CTE_rn
```

**Intermediate result**

```
+-----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------+-----+------+------+
| ProductId | DestinationId | ScheduledDate | Quantity | Price | rn1 | rn2  | Diff |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------+-----+------+------+
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-01    |        5 |     1 |   1 | 6665 | 6664 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-02    |       10 |     2 |   1 | 6666 | 6665 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-03    |        7 |     2 |   2 | 6667 | 6665 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-06-01    |        5 |     2 |   3 | 6726 | 6723 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-06-02    |       10 |     2 |   4 | 6727 | 6723 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-06-03    |        7 |     2 |   5 | 6728 | 6723 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-07    |       15 |     5 |   1 | 6701 | 6700 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-08    |       23 |     5 |   2 | 6702 | 6700 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-09    |       52 |     5 |   3 | 6703 | 6700 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-10    |       12 |    20 |   1 | 6704 | 6703 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-11    |       14 |    20 |   2 | 6705 | 6703 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-07    |       15 |    20 |   3 | 6732 | 6729 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-08    |       23 |    20 |   4 | 6733 | 6729 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-09    |       52 |    20 |   5 | 6734 | 6729 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-10    |       12 |    20 |   6 | 6735 | 6729 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-11    |       14 |    20 |   7 | 6736 | 6729 |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------+-----+------+------+
```

Now simply group by the `Diff` to get one row per interval.

**Final query**

```
WITH
CTE_Prices
AS
(
    SELECT
        History.ProductId
        ,History.DestinationId
        ,History.ScheduledDate
        ,History.Quantity
        ,A.Price
    FROM
        History
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP(1)
                PriceChange.Price
            FROM
                PriceChange
            WHERE
                PriceChange.ProductID = History.ProductID
                AND PriceChange.DestinationId = History.DestinationId
                AND PriceChange.EffectiveDate <= History.ScheduledDate
            ORDER BY
                PriceChange.EffectiveDate DESC
        ) AS A
)
,CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        ProductId
        ,DestinationId
        ,ScheduledDate
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, DestinationId, Price ORDER BY ScheduledDate) AS rn1
        ,DATEDIFF(day, '20000101', ScheduledDate) AS rn2
    FROM
        CTE_Prices
)
SELECT
    ProductId
    ,DestinationId
    ,MIN(ScheduledDate) AS StartDate
    ,MAX(ScheduledDate) AS EndDate
    ,SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
    ,Price
FROM
    CTE_rn
GROUP BY
    ProductId
    ,DestinationId
    ,Price
    ,rn2-rn1
ORDER BY
    ProductID
    ,DestinationId
    ,StartDate
;
```

**Final result**

```
+-----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------------+-------+
| ProductId | DestinationId | StartDate  |  EndDate   | TotalQuantity | Price |
+-----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------------+-------+
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-01 |             5 |     1 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-02 | 2018-04-03 |            17 |     2 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-03 |            22 |     2 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-07 | 2018-05-09 |            90 |     5 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-10 | 2018-05-11 |            26 |    20 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-07 | 2018-06-11 |           116 |    20 |
+-----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: I think there is a way to make it more efficient. I'll write a second variant tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you :) I selected this answer rather than your updated one because it performed better on my actual data, as well as this answer provided better quality results (your second attempt had islands without gaps or price changes, so it was doing more splitting than necessary).

For references, this answer takes 13 seconds to run on my machine, your other answer took 22 seconds. A simple "Select * from History" call takes 17 seconds to execute on the large table

Comment: @Carson, I'm surprised that my answers produce different results. I thought they should produce exactly the same results. If you are interested and want to get to the bottom of it, please provide some sample data that would yield different results for my two queries. (it would be a test case, essentially)  But, if you've got a "good enough" variant and don't have time for it, I totally understand. It is just my curiosity.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more variant that is likely to perform better than my first answer. I decided to put it as a second answer, because the approach is rather different and the answer would be too long. You should compare performance of all variants with your real data on your hardware, and don't forget about indexes.

In the first variant I was using `APPLY` to pick a relevant price for each row in the `History` table. For each row from the `History` table the engine is searching for a relevant row from the `PriceChange` table. Even with appropriate index on the `PriceChange` table when this is done via a single seek, it still means 3.7 million seeks in a loop join.

We can simply join `History` and `PriceChange` tables together and with appropriate indexes on both tables it will be an efficient merge join.

Here I'm also using an extended sample data set to illustrate the gaps. I added these rows to the sample data from the question.

```
INSERT INTO History (ProductId, DestinationId, ScheduledDate, Quantity)
VALUES
  (0, 1000, '20180601', 5),
  (0, 1000, '20180602', 10),
  (0, 1000, '20180603', 7),
  (3, 5000, '20180607', 15),
  (3, 5000, '20180608', 23),
  (3, 5000, '20180609', 52),
  (3, 5000, '20180610', 12),
  (3, 5000, '20180611', 14);
```

**Intermediate query**

We do a `FULL JOIN` here, not a `LEFT JOIN` because it is possible that the date on which the price changed doesn't appear in the `History` table at all.

```
WITH
CTE_Join
AS
(
    SELECT
        ISNULL(History.ProductId, PriceChange.ProductID) AS ProductID
        ,ISNULL(History.DestinationId, PriceChange.DestinationId) AS DestinationId
        ,ISNULL(History.ScheduledDate, PriceChange.EffectiveDate) AS ScheduledDate
        ,History.Quantity
        ,PriceChange.Price
    FROM
        History
        FULL JOIN PriceChange
            ON  PriceChange.ProductID = History.ProductID
            AND PriceChange.DestinationId = History.DestinationId
            AND PriceChange.EffectiveDate = History.ScheduledDate
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        ProductID
        ,DestinationId
        ,ScheduledDate
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN Price IS NOT NULL THEN ScheduledDate END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID, DestinationId ORDER BY ScheduledDate 
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grp
    FROM CTE_Join
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY
    ProductID
    ,DestinationId
    ,ScheduledDate
```

Create the following indexes

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_History] ON [dbo].[History]
(
    [ProductId] ASC,
    [DestinationId] ASC,
    [ScheduledDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([Quantity])

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Price] ON [dbo].[PriceChange]
(
    [ProductId] ASC,
    [DestinationId] ASC,
    [EffectiveDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([Price])
```

and the join will be an efficient `MERGE` join in the execution plan (not a `LOOP` join)

[image: merge join]

**Intermediate result**

```
+-----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------+------------+
| ProductID | DestinationId | ScheduledDate | Quantity | Price |    grp     |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------+------------+
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-02-01    | NULL     | 1     | 2018-02-01 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-01    | 5        | NULL  | 2018-02-01 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-02    | 10       | 2     | 2018-04-02 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-03    | 7        | NULL  | 2018-04-02 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-06-01    | 5        | NULL  | 2018-04-02 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-06-02    | 10       | NULL  | 2018-04-02 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-06-03    | 7        | NULL  | 2018-04-02 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-01-01    | NULL     | 5     | 2018-01-01 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-07    | 15       | NULL  | 2018-01-01 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-08    | 23       | NULL  | 2018-01-01 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-09    | 52       | NULL  | 2018-01-01 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-10    | 12       | 20    | 2018-05-10 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-11    | 14       | NULL  | 2018-05-10 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-07    | 15       | NULL  | 2018-05-10 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-08    | 23       | NULL  | 2018-05-10 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-09    | 52       | NULL  | 2018-05-10 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-10    | 12       | NULL  | 2018-05-10 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-11    | 14       | NULL  | 2018-05-10 |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

You can see that the `Price` column has a lot of `NULL` values. We need to "fill" these NULL values with the preceding non-NULL value.

Itzik Ben-Gan wrote a nice article showing how to solve this efficiently [The Last non NULL Puzzle](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle). Also see [Best way to replace NULL with most recent non-null value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48106564/4116017).

This is done in `CTE2` using `MAX` window function and you can see how it populates the `grp` column. This requires SQL Server 2012+. After the groups are determined we should remove rows where `Quantity` is NULL, because these rows are not from the `History` table.

Now we can do the same gaps-and-islands step using the `grp` column as an additional partitioning.

The rest of the query is pretty much the same as in the first variant.

**Final query**

```
WITH
CTE_Join
AS
(
    SELECT
        ISNULL(History.ProductId, PriceChange.ProductID) AS ProductID
        ,ISNULL(History.DestinationId, PriceChange.DestinationId) AS DestinationId
        ,ISNULL(History.ScheduledDate, PriceChange.EffectiveDate) AS ScheduledDate
        ,History.Quantity
        ,PriceChange.Price
    FROM
        History
        FULL JOIN PriceChange
            ON  PriceChange.ProductID = History.ProductID
            AND PriceChange.DestinationId = History.DestinationId
            AND PriceChange.EffectiveDate = History.ScheduledDate
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        ProductID
        ,DestinationId
        ,ScheduledDate
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN Price IS NOT NULL THEN ScheduledDate END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID, DestinationId ORDER BY ScheduledDate 
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grp
    FROM CTE_Join
)
,CTE_RN
AS
(
    SELECT
        ProductID
        ,DestinationId
        ,ScheduledDate
        ,grp
        ,Quantity
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, DestinationId, grp ORDER BY ScheduledDate) AS rn1
        ,DATEDIFF(day, '20000101', ScheduledDate) AS rn2
    FROM CTE2
    WHERE Quantity IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    ProductId
    ,DestinationId
    ,MIN(ScheduledDate) AS StartDate
    ,MAX(ScheduledDate) AS EndDate
    ,SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
FROM
    CTE_RN
GROUP BY
    ProductId
    ,DestinationId
    ,grp
    ,rn2-rn1
ORDER BY
    ProductID
    ,DestinationId
    ,StartDate
;
```

**Final result**

```
+-----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------------+
| ProductId | DestinationId | StartDate  |  EndDate   | TotalQuantity |
+-----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------------+
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-01 |             5 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-04-02 | 2018-04-03 |            17 |
|         0 |          1000 | 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-03 |            22 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-07 | 2018-05-09 |            90 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-05-10 | 2018-05-11 |            26 |
|         3 |          5000 | 2018-06-07 | 2018-06-11 |           116 |
+-----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

This variant doesn't output the relevant price (as the first variant), because I simplified the "last non-null" query. It wasn't required in the question. In any case, it is pretty easy to add the price if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that i understand correctly, but this is just my idea:

```
Select concat_ws(',',view2.StartDate,  string_agg(view1.splitDate, ','), 
 view2.EndDate), view2.productId, view2.DestinationId from (
 SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY EffectiveDate) as Rank, EffectiveDate as 
  SplitDate FROM PriceChange GROUP BY EffectiveDate) view1 join 
 (
     SELECT MIN(ScheduledDate) as StartDate, MAX(ScheduledDate) as 
       EndDate,ProductId, DestinationId, SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity
     FROM (
      SELECT ScheduledDate, DestinationId, ProductId, PartitionGroup = 
      DATEADD(DAY ,-1 * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ScheduledDate), 
       ScheduledDate), Quantity
       FROM History
   ) tmp
      GROUP BY PartitionGroup, DestinationId, ProductId
    ) view2 on view1.SplitDate >= view2.StartDate 
      and view1.SplitDate <=view2.EndDate 
      group by view2.startDate, view2.endDate, view2.productId, 
      view2.DestinationId
```

The result from this query will be:

```
| ranges                                      | productId | DestinationId |
|---------------------------------------------|-----------|---------------|
| 2018-04-01,2018-04-02,2018-04-03            | 0         | 1000          |
| 2018-05-07,2018-05-10,2018-05-11            | 3         | 5000          |
```

Then, with any procedure language, for each row, you can split the string (with appropriate inclusive or exclusive rule for each boundary) to find out a list of condition (:from, :to, :productId, :destinationId).

And finally, you can loop through the list of conditions and use **Union all** clause to build one query (which is the union of all queries, which states a condition) to find out the final result. For example,

```
Select * from History where ScheduledDate >= '2018-04-01' and ScheduledDate <'2018-04-02' and productId = 0 and destinationId = 1000 
union all
Select * from History where ScheduledDate >= '2018-04-02' and ScheduledDate <'2018-04-03' and productId = 0 and destinationId = 1000
```

----Update--------

Just based on above idea, i do some quick changes to provide your resultset. Maybe you can optimize it later

```
 with view3 as 
(Select concat_ws(',',view2.StartDate,  string_agg(view1.splitDate, ','), 
 dateadd(day, 1, view2.EndDate)) dateRange, view2.productId, view2.DestinationId from (
 SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY EffectiveDate) as Rank, EffectiveDate as 
  SplitDate FROM PriceChange GROUP BY EffectiveDate) view1 join 
 (
     SELECT MIN(ScheduledDate) as StartDate, MAX(ScheduledDate) as 
       EndDate,ProductId, DestinationId, SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity
     FROM (
      SELECT ScheduledDate, DestinationId, ProductId, PartitionGroup = 
      DATEADD(DAY ,-1 * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ScheduledDate), 
       ScheduledDate), Quantity
       FROM History
   ) tmp
      GROUP BY PartitionGroup, DestinationId, ProductId
    ) view2 on view1.SplitDate >= view2.StartDate 
      and view1.SplitDate <=view2.EndDate 
      group by view2.startDate, view2.endDate, view2.productId, 
      view2.DestinationId
),
 view4 as
(
select productId, destinationId, value from view3 cross apply string_split(dateRange, ',')
 ),
 view5 as(
   select *, row_number() over(partition by productId, destinationId order by value) rn from view4
 ),
 view6 as (
   select v52.value fr, v51.value t, v51.productid, v51. destinationid from view5 v51 join view5 v52
 on v51.productid = v52.productid
 and v51.destinationid = v52.destinationid
 and v51.rn = v52.rn+1
 )
 select min(h.ScheduledDate) StartDate, max(h.ScheduledDate) EndDate, v6.productId, v6.destinationId, sum(h.quantity) TotalQuantity from view6 v6 join History h 
 on v6.destinationId = h.destinationId
 and v6.productId = h.productId
 and h.ScheduledDate >= v6.fr
 and h.ScheduledDate <v6.t
 group by v6.fr, v6.t, v6.productId, v6.destinationId
```

And the result is exactly the same with what you gave.

```
| StartDate  | EndDate    | productId | destinationId | TotalQuantity |
|------------|------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|
| 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-01 | 0         | 1000          | 5             |
| 2018-04-02 | 2018-04-03 | 0         | 1000          | 17            |
| 2018-05-07 | 2018-05-09 | 3         | 5000          | 90            |
| 2018-05-10 | 2018-05-11 | 3         | 5000          | 26            |
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. The one thing it doesn't satisfy in the desired results is I need the TotalQuantity for each date range, however I'm sure that could similarly be concat'd in there

Comment: This solution did not work for me in the end, as I need the quantities accurately summed up by the new, split date ranges. I am just letting you know I have now put a bounty on this question, in case you choose to attempt it again.

Comment: @thanhngo, I may be misunderstanding the question, but your last query doesn't seem to work correctly with multiple gaps. Try to extend the sample data as I did.

Answer (score 1):

Use `outer apply` to choose the nearest price, then do a `group by`:

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/af568/65

```sql
select 
    StartDate = min(h.ScheduledDate),
    EndDate = max(h.ScheduledDate),
    h.ProductId,
    h.DestinationId,
    TotalQuantity = sum(h.Quantity)
from History h
outer apply
(
    select top 1 pc.*
    from PriceChange pc
    where 
        pc.ProductId = h.ProductId
        and pc.Effectivedate <= h.ScheduledDate
    order by pc.EffectiveDate desc
) UpToDate
group by UpToDate.EffectiveDate,
    h.ProductId,
    h.DestinationId
order by StartDate, EndDate, ProductId
```

Output:

```
|  StartDate |    EndDate | ProductId | DestinationId | TotalQuantity |
|------------|------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|
| 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-01 |         0 |          1000 |             5 |
| 2018-04-02 | 2018-04-03 |         0 |          1000 |            17 |
| 2018-05-07 | 2018-05-09 |         3 |          5000 |            90 |
| 2018-05-10 | 2018-05-11 |         3 |          5000 |            26 |
```

Comment: Sample data in the question doesn't illustrate it properly, that's why I added few more rows to the sample data in my answer. Sample data in the question doesn't show where the gaps and islands are. I think that your variant doesn't take these possible gaps into account.